# MySQL count child elements

Tags: php, mysql, adjacency-list

I have a categories table:

```
id | name |  parent_id
1  | Camaro | 0
2  | Chevelle | 0
3  | Sale - Camaro Parts | 1
4  | Bestselling Parts | 1
```

My first request looks like:

```
'SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
    `categories`
 WHERE
    parent_id = :parent_id';
```

And after I'm fetching result set I make sub query to check if row has child elements:

```
foreach($result as $r) {
    $r->hasChild    = count(ORM::forTable('categories')->where('parent_id', $r->id)->findArray());
    $data[]         = $r;
}
```

Is any way to avoid multiple connection to DB in foreach loop and get data in first query?

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT 
   count(*) 
 FROM 
    `categories`
 WHERE
    parent_id = :parent_id;`

Comment: Thank! But how to Left Join it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't awful to do, so long as you only want the count of children below the selected rows. If you want the entire hierarchy, you'll need to use a better RDMS.

The main part of the solution here is self joining the same table. Then we can use the `count()` aggregate function to see how many children are attached to each item.

```sql
select
  categories.id
  , categories.name
  , categories.parent_id
  , count(chld.id)
from
  categories
  left join categories chld
    on categories.id = chld.parent_id
where
  parent_id = :parent_id
group by
  categories.id
  , categories.name
  , categories.parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join to the table on parent_id and id. Based on whether you want categories with child or not you can do a left join or inner join. Kind of a similar question is mentioned here -
[Mysql Self Join to find a parent child relationship in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694986/mysql-self-join-to-find-a-parent-child-relationship-in-the-same-table)